# Trouble with CSV-Helper not converting bool values

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, csvhelper

I'm starting to use [CSV Helper](http://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/) - an excellent little helper for your daily work - great stuff!

One item I'm struggling with right now are *class maps* - I have a little class

```
public class SimpleClass
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal Percentage { get; set; }
    public bool IsValid { get; set; }
}
```

and for exporting to CSV, I would like to replace the `IsValid` values `true` with `yes`, `False` with `no`; for that purpose, I've created a class map:

```
public class SimpleClassMap : CsvClassMap<SimpleClass>
{
    public override void CreateMap()
    {
        Map(x => x.ID).Index(0);
        Map(x => x.Name).Index(1);
        Map(x => x.Percentage).Index(2);
        Map(x => x.IsValid).Index(3)
                           .TypeConverterOption(true, "yes")
                           .TypeConverterOption(false, "no");
    }
}
```

and now when exporting my data, I'm using that class map:

```
CsvConfiguration config = new CsvConfiguration { Delimiter = ";", HasHeaderRecord = false, Quote = '"' };
config.RegisterClassMap<SimpleClassMap>();

using (MemoryStream stm = new MemoryStream())
using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(stm))
using (var csvWriter = new CsvWriter(streamWriter, config))
{
    csvWriter.WriteRecords(list);
    streamWriter.Flush();
}
```

Unfortunately, when I inspect what has been written, I see that I still get `True` or `False` - not the `yes` or `no` as I had hoped.....

What am I missing here? I'm using CSV-Helper v2.5, installed from NuGet, and .NET 4.0 / Visual Studio 2010.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The boolean values overload for `TypeConverterOption` is used only when reading. It allows you to specify multiple values that can be used for true/false when reading. So you could do `1`, `"true"`, `"TRUE"`, `"True"`, `"yes"`, etc.

Currently the only way to do it when writing is to create a custom type converter.

```
public class MyBooleanConverter : DefaultTypeConverter
{
    public override string ConvertToString( TypeConverterOptions options, object value )
    {
        if( value == null )
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }

        var boolValue = (bool)value;

        return boolValue ? "yes" : "no";
    }
}
```

You can then apply it to all booleans globally.

```
CsvHelper.TypeConversion.TypeConverterFactory.AddConverter<bool>( new MyBooleanConverter() );
```

Or apply it to a single property via the mapping.

```
Map( m => m.MyBoolProperty ).TypeConverter<MyBooleanConverter>();
```

Comment: Yes, I know. :( The next major version will have the configs separated out by reader and writer, instead of one big config pool.

Comment: Is there any way of passing in a value to the TypeConvertor? I basically want to replace any null values with a specified length string (padding fields in the csv to meet a specification)

Comment: Can you post this on the github issues page? We can share code examples that way.https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper/issues

Answer (score 5):

The accepted solution doesn't work with latest versions. I am using `CsvHelper 15.0.0` and this is how it works.

```
public class MyBooleanConverter : DefaultTypeConverter
{
    public override string ConvertToString(object value, IWriterRow row, MemberMapData memberMapData)
    {
        if( value == null )
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }
        var boolValue = (bool)value;
        return boolValue ? "yes" : "no";
    }
}
```

Applying to single property:

```
Map(x => x.IsValid).Index(3).TypeConverter<MyBooleanConverter>();
```

Applying from configuration of reader/writter:

```
using var csvWriter = new CsvWriter(new StreamWriter(path), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
csvWriter.Configuration.TypeConverterCache.AddConverter<bool>(new MyBooleanConverter());
csvWriter.WriteRecords(data);
```

Comment: Notice that the order is important - the call to Context.TypeConverterCache.AddConverter should appear before any mappings, e.g. by calling Context.RegisterClassMap.

Answer (score 4):

You can just use attributes for that:

```
    [BooleanFalseValues("N")]
    [BooleanTrueValues("Y")]
    public bool IsValid { get; init; }
```